# after adding header cells don't appear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header

I have big image and after this I have table view. This two elements are on scroll view, and table view :

```
scrollEnabled = false
```

I had two cells in my tableView, and their height was counting by function in cell file(cause text in cells is dynamic)

```
func configure(#comment: Comment) {

    userCommentTextView.text = comment.comment
    userCommentTextView.accessibilityLabel = "Quote Content"
    userCommentTextView.accessibilityValue = comment.comment

}
```

all was ok, I was counting scrollview size like

```
scrollView.contentSize.height = tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.frame.height
```

in   `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {} delegate

BUT after I added custom header, all cells are not visible, there is only my header! Why? what is the problem? I checked, there is info for cells. And

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return comments.count
}
```

is NOT nil. But cellforrowindexpath isn't even executing. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your headerview by

```
func tableView(viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView {}
```

and call

```
func tableView(heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {}
```

also

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView() -> Int{}
```

Comment: Do you only have one header, or will there be multiple headers?

Comment: 1 header, for 1 section. in this 1 section there are dynamic cells with dynamic height, function for counting dynamic height is in my question